# How to send a different email to CC and TO without creating 2 mail objects? ASP CLASSIC

Tags: email, asp-classic

I was wondering if it is possible to send a different paragraph in the mail body to the CC that isn't being send to the TO address?

I rather not send 2 emails to the CC address and TO address since the email differs only in a small part, namely on only one paragraph. 
So I thought about having a simple IF/THEN statement in the Body of the email, when CC is the receiver of the email then show this paragraph, else don't. Though I have no clue if this is even possible, also after some research I didn't found anything about it.

To make it a bit clearer, here my email code:

```
        Function SendMail(sBody,sEmail)

            set mail=server.createobject("Persits.MailSender")
            Mail.Host = "spamfilter.mywebsite.com" 
            Mail.Port = 587 ' Optional. Port is 25 by default 

            Mail.From = "support@mysite.com"
            Mail.FromName = "MyName"

            sEmail = request.Form("EMail")

            Mail.AddAddress sEmail
            Mail.AddCC "support@mysite.com"

            Mail.Subject = "Some subject"
            Mail.Body = sBody
            Mail.IsHTML = True 
            Mail.send

        End Function
```

**The email body:**

```
                sBody="<font face=""Verdana, Arial"" size=2 color=""black"">Dear " & FormName & ",<br><br>"
                sBody=sBody & "Recently you made a ticket concerning '<b>" & FormSubject &  "</b>'.<br>"
                sBody=sBody & "We will try to answer your question as soon as possible" & "<br><br>"

                'THE IF/THEN FOR CC SHOULD COME HERE FOR THE NEXT BODY PART
                sBody=sBody & "The company that send this ticket is:" & FormCompany &",<br><br>"
                'END THE CC IF              

                sBody=sBody &  "<br>"

                err=SendMail(sBody,sEmail)
```

You might think that this email can easily be send twice since its not that big but I posted not the entire body text now, it is actually quite more.

Comment: No, you will need to restructure the body possibly build it separately and make the e-mail sending more generic.

Comment: Everybody receiving the __same__ e-mail, whether it be addressed in TO, CC or BCC will get the same body content. If you want different body content, then you must send different e-mails. Creating the e-mail can be done genericly as proposed by Lankymart

Comment: Ah alright, thank you both for the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible and makes no sense. In case you need different text, you should send different messages.

```
err=SendMail("...",sEmail)  
err=SendMail("...The company that send....",sEmail2)
```